# adding a drop down filter in KQL chart

Tags: azure, charts, kql

I have a chart in azure monitor (app insight to be exact) essentially I have 5 servers 2 of which are used by client B and 3 by client C. what I want to all server displayed but a drop down option so client B or c can be chosen

At the moment I have two charts which show the servers stood alone and another combined

With the following query

```
Perf

|extend iif(Computer =="X","B",iif(Computer =="Y","B","C")) | where CounterName == "% Processor Time" | where ObjectName == "Processor" | where Computer contains "SQL" | summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5min), iif(Computer =="X","B",iif(Computer
=="Y","B","C")) // bin is used to set the time grain to 15 minutes | render timechart
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-dropdowns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A solution that may work for you*

*As suggested by [Peter Bons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932728/peter-bons) and after testing in our local environment.*

- *In your application insights create a workbook with a new parameter*
- *Pick "**dropdown**" as the parameter type*
- *Pick "**query**" as "**get data from**" option*
- *Set your **data source** from where you are getting your data.*
- *The below query is for getting the list of subscriptions you can use your own query for getting the list of servers*

```
ResourceContainers | where type =~ "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
// add any other filters you want here
| project id, name, group=tenantId
```

[image]
[image]

- *For further information you can go through the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-dropdowns).*

Comment: I have tried the above and now have managed to create the parameter but I cant get the KQL to pick it up